# the data of an input field not on one line will all browsers accept it?

Tags: html, browser, syntax

Hi im working on a system with inputfields.
Normaly i put the input field on one line but now i have made it like this below

```
    <input
    type='text'
    name='alg_persoonsgegevens_achternaam'
    id='alg_persoonsgegevens_achternaam'
    class='text dontprintinput'
    value='xxxxxxx'
    maxlength='50'
    size='20'
/>
```

I was wonderdering if ALL browsers (also IE6..) accept this way because the input is not on one line and I have never seen anyone do it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is valid HTML, so all browsers that can render valid HTML will accept this.

In most cases, different kinds of whitespace are interchangeable, and in this case using a newline is no different than using a space.